# Django - Defining variable in a models helper function?

Tags: django, variables, django-models

This is my models.py (I'm creating a forum):

```
class Post(models.Model): #users can make a post
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    actualPost = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class PostReply(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post) #each post can have multiple replies
    replyTo = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True) #each reply can also have multiple replies. 
                                                               #If replyTo = None, then the reply is a direct reply to the post
                                                               #If the user is replying to an existing reply, then replyTo will link to the reply which the user is replying to
    actualReply = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    replyCounter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

So let's say a user creates a post. Someone replies to the post (basically, a PostReply object will be created where replyTo = None - the reply is directed at the post). If someone replies to the reply, then a PostReply object will be created where replyTo = the reply which was directed at the post.

I need to give each reply a counter. If the reply is a direct reply to the post (replyTo=None) then it is given a counter of 0. If it is a reply to a reply, it is given a counter of 1. If it is a reply to a reply to a reply, it is given a counter of 2 etc.

This is the helper function which I created for PostReply:

```
def get_replyCount(self):
    if self.replyTo: #if the reply is a reply to another reply (and not a direct reply to the post)
        while self.replyTo != None:
            self = self.replyTo
            replyCounter += 1
             get_replyCount(self)
        return replyCounter
    else:
        return None
```

Now if a variable called 'reply' (which is a PostReply object) is passed to the template and in the template, if I do

```
{{ reply.get_replyCount }}
```

it gives me a

```
UnboundLocalError at /urlWhichITriedToAccess/
local variable 'replyCounter' referenced before assignment
```

How do I declare the variable for my models helper function? I tried making it a field in the model but it did not work. I also tried to declare it at the beginning of models.py but that didn't work (for obvious reasons, I need one variable for each instance of PostReply).

Comment: Wow.. what is this `self = self.replyTo` doing? Also, you forgot to initialize `replyCounter`

Comment: @karthikr I basically wanted to make "self / this post to be equal to the post it replied to" and then add one to the counter and do the function again with the self.replyTo post.. basically keep on going to the post which self replied to until it didn't reply to post, and that's when I return the counter.. you get what I mean? Also, yea, where exactly so I initialize replyCounter? I tried to initialize it at the beginning of models.py but then realized that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try some recursive function like

```
def get_replyCount(self):
    if self.replyTo: #if the reply is a reply to another reply (and not a direct reply to the post)
        replyCounter = 0
        while self.replyTo != None:
            self = self.replyTo
            replyCounter += get_replyCount(self) +1
        return replyCounter
    else:
        return 1
```

This should work return the correct number of replies.
If there are more then one reply it will iterate through this list and add "1" for each object until the end of the list.
If there is only one reply (or for the last item) it will jump to the else condition and return 1 that the count is at least 1.
But since you call this function on replies only it will always be a minimum of 1.

Comment: right, but since you initialize replyCounter=0 inside the function, after the line "replyCounter += get_replyCount(self) + 1", it will execute the get_replyCount function again and will assign replyCounter to equal 0 every time the function is called.. I need to initialize the variable outside of the function but I'm not sure how

Comment: not every time at the breaking condition it will return 1 (the else condition) and move backwards and add 1 for each time the function was called which is equal to the number of replys

Comment: and of course replyCounter has to be a local variable and is initialized in the function and finally the number of replies is the return value and stored in the local replyCounter